# How can i migrate my typo3 web application to another server

Tags: migration, typo3, content-management-system

Already i have website created with typo3 and we have to change the current server with another server.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to copy over all the files starting with the project root (where public,var, vendor folders are located) and export/import the database.
After this you need to adjust some settings in your LocalConfiguration.php and/or AddidionalConfiguration.php or .env file like database credentials, aso.

If you have a deployment set up (what is recommended) you can just set up a new deployment node/target, export/import the database and deploy to the new server.

If you need more detail help you should add some more information about your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and we have Ubuntu16.04 version and the control panel is Plesk

Comment: Well I thought more of TYPO3 specific things. Is it a composer installation? Do you use .env file? How do you deploy to the server(s)? Other then that what have you tried so far?

Comment: No .env file and there is a folder contain another folder for composer